# Is energy-momentum of curvature a boundary/holographic density?

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, covariance

Since the beginnings of General Relativity, we have had this awkward, unholy separation of the universe in marble versus wood. divergence of the stress-energy momentum holds at all points of space-time covariantly, and yet none of those flows result in a covariant density of gravitational stress-energy.

But obviously marble-like gravitational waves can exert work on wood-like matter and electromagnetic waves, and wood-like spinning binaries can emit marble-like gravitational waves, Our beloved conservation of wood-like point-like stress-energy conservation $\partial_{\mu}T_{\mu \nu}=0$ seems to hold even while spinning binaries lose energy, and gravitational waves are emitted. But gravitational energy is not a covariant quantity. "It becomes spread out", we are told

Certainly it seems that gravitational energy is not a volumetric density tensor, and any attempts to construct such quantity have been either non-tensorial or trivially zero. But could it be that gravitational energy is actually a surface density tensor? Could there be a description of gravitational field as a boundary-tensor?

moreover, is there a mathematical formalism for describing such things as 'boundary tensors'?